# Cauchy problem has no global solution (Lee Smooth Manifolds 9.23.c)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

$\def \pux{ {\partial u \over \partial x}}
\def \puy{ {\partial u \over \partial y}}
\def \px{ {\partial \over \partial x}}
\def \pz{ {\partial \over \partial z}}
\def \py{{ \partial \over \partial y}}$
In Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds text, problem **9-22.c** is to find a solution to the quasilinear Cauchy problem:

$$ \pux + u\puy = y, \qquad \text{ with } u(0, y) = 0$$

Using the method of characteristics, I found the solution:

$$u(x,y) =  y\left( {e^x - e^{-x} \over e^x + e^{-x}} \right)$$

Problem **9.23.c** is to show that 9.22.c has no global solutions. The solution for $u$ above seems valid $\forall x,y\in \Bbb R^2$.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does it mean for a solution to be _global_? What happens to the solution as $y \to \infty$?

Comment: I assume it means the solution is defined for all of $\Bbb R^2$, which this solution is.

Answer (score 2):

You're right -- this problem was incorrectly stated in the book. There's a corrected version in my [correction list](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/). (It would probably be a good idea to download that list and keep it nearby while you read!)

Sorry for the confusion.